# Android 6.0 and Blackberry 10 unable to focus on input in Cordova/Phonegap App

Tags: android, cordova, blackberry, phonegap-build

As the title says, somehow on the android 6 and Blackberry 10 in my cordova project i am unable to focus on the input text field. The virtual keyboard opens, and then focus disappears (on the input) and keyboard closes as well.

This happened on the Nexus 5 and Blackberry Leap.

iOS, WP8 and Android devices with ICS and JB are working fine as they should,

Hope someone had the similar issue.

Cheers